# Disable touch events on certain areas of iPhone screen

Tags: iphone, objective-c, input, user-input, touches

I want to disable touches on all areas of the screen apart from a specific few points (e.g buttons). I.e. I don't want 'touchesBegan' to trigger at all when I tap anything other than a button. Calling

```
    self.view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

has the desired effect for not registering touches, but then of course I can't tap any buttons. I basically want the button to still work, **even if there are 5 points touching the screen, i.e. all touch inputs have been used up, and the button represents the 6th.**

Is this possible?

I've tried inserting a view with userInteraction disabled below my buttons, but it still registers touches when the user taps the screen. It seems the only way to disable touch registering is to do so on the entire screen (on the parent UIView).

UPDATE: 
I've tried using gesture recognizers to handle all touch events, and ignore those that don't qualify. Here is my code:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>
```

...

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIGestureRecognizer *allRecognizer = [[UIGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:nil];
    allRecognizer.delegate = self;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:allRecognizer];
}

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {
    CGPoint coords = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    NSLog(@"Coords: %g, %g", coords.x, coords.y);
    if (coords.y < 200) {
    [self ignoreTouch:touch forEvent:nil];
    return TRUE;
}
return FALSE;

}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    NSLog(@"%i touch(es)", [touches count]);
}
```

However the screen still 'reads' the touches, so if I place 5 fingers down, the 6th one won't trigger a button press...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to set up an invisible UIButton and lay it between the view that should not register touches and the UIButtons that should still be active.

Now you need to set the invisible button's 'userInteractionEnabled':

```
//userInteractionEnabled == NO  => self.view registeres touches
//userInteractionEnabled == YES => self.view doesn't register touches
[_invisibleButton setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
```

What really matters in this solution is that both - the invisible and the visible buttons are direct subviews of the VC's view.

You can download an example project from my dropbox:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/99449487/DontTapThat.zip

However this example just prevents the handling of certain touches. Completly ignoring input isn't technically possible:  Third party apps are not responsible for for *detecting* input. They are just responsible for *handling* input. The detection of touch input is done iOS.

The only way to build up a case like you describe it in the comments is to hope that iOS won't interpret the input of your case as a "finger" because it's most likely going to cover an area that's way bigger than a finger.

So in conclusion the best way would be to change the material of the case you're about to build or at least give it a non conductive coating. From a third party developers point of view there is no way to achieve your goals with software if there is a need for 5 fingers as described in the comments.

Comment: Thanks for the code, however I'm afraid it still doesn't do what I need. Yes, it doesn't trigger touchesBegan, however it still registers touch points on the screen. So if you touch the screen with 5 fingers and then use a 6th to tap any of the buttons, it doesn't read. I realise it's a bit of an odd problem..

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't have a valid program enrollment at the moment to test that out. I don't know what the problem with registering touchesBegan is for you but I think the easiest way would be to forget about that invisible button and just set up a BOOL indicates whether to use the code inside touchesBegan or not. Like if (_useCode) {}

Edit: That is just for that 5th and 6th finger case, right? I think there was something about a finger limit of 5 fingers at the same time on iPhone. The 6th finger would not be registered no matter what you do.

Comment: There is indeed a 5 finger limit, but I was hoping that if you ignored fingers that weren't in the 'correct' place, it would only read the ones that were. But it seems that no matter what you do, it will still read a point of contact with the screen, regardless of whether or not you handle the touch... I'm basically working on a case that covers part of the screen, but is made of conductive material, and I don't want it triggering touch points on the surface. Well, thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: There is currently no way of completly ignoring a finger on the screen  because third party apps aren't responsible for finger detection itself. So there is no way an app could technically completly ignore input. I don't now exactly what kind of case you're going to build but conductive material may not be the best choice. The only thing that could work out is that iOS is looking for fingers - not surfaces. So if you lay your full side of your hand on the device there is a chance on iOS not detecting it as a 'finger'. But most likely choosing another material or a thin coating may be best.

Comment: I think you're right - it's not possible to ignore points of contact, only to change how you handle them. I'll have to experiment a bit more with how I design this case, and the materials used. Thanks for confirming that it's not possible though. If you could add your comments to your answer, I'll accept it with the bounty!

Answer (score 3):

There is couple of methods in UIView that you can override:

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;   // recursively calls -pointInside:withEvent:. point is in the receiver's coordinate system
- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;   // default returns YES if point is in bounds
```

This should prevent to call touchBegin and other methods.

Regards.

Comment: I think this presents the same problem though - the fingers touching the screen still count as points of contact, and there is still a limit of just 5.

Answer (score 0):

I have a nice solution for this. What ever the area you want to hide the interaction place a transparent button on top of the area.

Comment: But that transparent button will still read touch events, so if there were 5 points of contact on the button, will it still read a touch on the actual button?

Comment: Place your button on top of the area which you want to disable.Then go to button inspector and uncheck the User interaction enabled. Try this..

Comment: This doesn't work - 'touchesBegan' is still triggered when you tap on the interaction disabled button.

Answer (score 0):

touchesBegan is a default method so it must call all the time when touch happens on view so there is no way-out, But you can still do one thing set

```
self.buttonPlayMusic.userInteractionEnabled = FALSE;
```

for the object you don't need touch may be this could be help you with your desired output.

Comment: It doesn't - if I set userInteractionEnabled to FALSE on a button, it still triggers touchesBegan. TouchesBegan doesn't trigger however, if the entire root view is set to userInteractionEnabled = FALSE; So I need the latter behaviour, with the ability to add working buttons on top.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `UIImageView` Control on that area where you want to disable touch event.you can add `UIImageView` object as top of `self.view` subViews.

Example 
//area -- is that area where you want to disable touch on `self.view`

```
UIImageView *imageView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:area];

[self.view addSubView:imageView];
```

Comment: The UIImageView still triggers touchesBegan when tapped, even with interactionEnabled = FALSE; I want the touch to be completely unregistered.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a UIScrollView as the background ? i.e the area where you do not want touch events to be fired.

UIScrollView does not call the touch methods.

Comment: A nice suggestion, thanks. But although UIScrollView doesn't call touch events, it does in fact read contact points, so wouldn't work for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You touchDelegate will always call in this way, but if you are doing some task on touch then you can do your task like this way.

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    UIButton *touchObject=(UIButton*)[touch view];

    if ([touchObject isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
    {
        //Do what ever you want on button touch
    }
    else{
        return;
    }
}
```